# Kentico 10 OrderInfoProvider get order by guid

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am trying to get order info on the receipt page, based on the order guid from query /receipt.aspx?o=7f4e23bd-fb2d-4891-b0b2-7bbc2eaaacb5

So far I have this:
(code copied from facebook pixel widget, same page)

```
int orderID;
var oid = Request.QueryString["o"];

Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>console.log('" + oid +"');</script>");
// this works, logs to console the order id string

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oid) )
{
   int.TryParse(oid, out orderID);

   // If the text value is not a number, returns null
   if (orderID <= 0)
   {
     // 
   }
   else {
    // Gets the order based on the order ID
    OrderInfo order = OrderInfoProvider.GetOrderInfo(orderID);
                    
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>console.log('" + order + "');</script>");
}
}
```

I'm stuck at converting order GUID to int because `int.TryParse(oid, out orderID)` is returning 0. I am aware that it makes no sense to do this conversion

Comment: You can't convert GUID to int. The types are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm what was said by Cristian, you could also directly use Kentico's ValidationHelper to retrieve the Guid from the QueryString and then check if it is different from Guid.Empty.
Also you cannot use the .GetOrderInfo to retrieve the order via Guid because the latter only accepts the ID (int), the correct method is this in my example.

```
//var oid = Request.QueryString["o"];
var orderGuid = ValidationHelper.GetGuid(Request.QueryString["o"], Guid.Empty);

if (orderGuid != Guid.Empty)
{
    // Gets the order based on the order Guid
    OrderInfo order = OrderInfoProvider.GetOrders()
        .WhereEquals(nameof(OrderInfo.OrderGUID), orderGuid)
        .TopN(1)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my code is from a web part on the same page, and it seemed odd to try and convert uid(base_url/receipt.aspx?o=7f4e23bd-fb2d-4891-b0b2-7bbc2eaaacb5) of type string to an int...  then I tried the kentico docs - haven't found a solution to getting the order info on the receipt page... yet

Comment: you're welcome, the .FirstObject property is deprecated at least in the K12 version, I already recommend you replace it with `.FirstOrDefault()` of System.Linq

Comment: also you can mark my answer as "accepted" if i solved your problem

Comment: I wish I could, I don't have enough reputation to accept your answer. And you are right `.FirstOrDefault()` would be right for K12, but for K10 is `.FirstObject`